# How to change the name of request parameters in Spring Boot when using the Gson serializer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

```
// Class Definition
public class GenericRequest {
    @SerializedName("unique_id");
    private String uniqueId;

    public String id() {
        return uniqueId;
    }
}

// Controller
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
public ResponsePOJO getRequest(GenericRequest request) {
    return new ResponsePOJO(request.id());
}
```

When I use the parameter as `uniqueId` it is working perfectly, but when I use the `unique_id`, it is not able to populate the `uniqueId` field and set it as `null`. This is working perfectly for the fields annotated with `@SerializedName` in the response. I am using Spring Boot and Gson for serdes.

Comment: Your GenericRequest bean is incomplete, could you please paste it completely

Comment: @HemantPatel This is complete bean. I am able to get the request with this. Only problem is, I have to use `uniqueId` instead of `unique_id`